# Google Apps Script: Connecting to Amazon Selling Partner API (Access Token)

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm trying to connect to [Amazon Selling Partner API](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api) using Google Apps Script.

The first step based on the documentation is to generate an **access token** if we don't have one valid at the moment (Access tokens expire one hour after they have been generated).

For that we would need the following inputs:

- grant_type (parameter)
- refresh_token (input)
- scope (parameter)
- client_id (input)
- client_secret (input)

I'm trying to generate an access token for an operation that requires seller authorization

Here is my code so far:

```
const REFRESH_TOKEN = "MyRefreshToken";
const CLIENT_ID ="MyClientID";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "MyClientSecret"

function AccessToken(){
  var base_url = 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token';
  var pointParams = "?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + REFRESH_TOKEN + "&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET;
  var query_string = base_url + pointParams;

  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    //'Host': 'api.amazon.com' (ignored since we already provided the url in the base_url var)
  }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'headers': headers,
    //'muteHttpExceptions': true

  };

  var rawData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(query_string, options).getContentText();
  Logger.log('rawData: ' + rawData)
}
```

*Note: When we call an operation that requires seller authorization we will set the parameter `grant_type = refresh_token` and in this case the `scope` parameter should not be included*

This is the example code provided by the website:

```
POST /auth/o2/token HTTP/l.l
Host: api.amazon.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
grant_type=refresh_token
&refresh_token=Aztr|...
&client_id=foodev
&client_secret=Y76SDl2F
```

**PROBLEM**

I'm getting a 500 server error:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.amazon.com returned code
> 500. Truncated server response: {} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) AccessToken   @ API.gs:30

Using `'muteHttpExceptions': true` only shows that the result of the UrlFetchapp is blank

**QUESTIONS**

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_DE/dev_guide/DG_Errors.html) a 500 error is described as

> There was an internal service failure.

However I would like to ask if there is some part of my code that I could improve or something else I could check since the response doesn't give me any leads.

**UPDATE #1**

Here are the formats of the const variables:

- REFRESH_TOKEN: Atzr|[a-zA-Z0-9-]*
- CLIENT_ID: amzn1.application-oa2-client.[a-z0-9]{32}
- CLIENT_SECRET: [a-z0-9]{64}

In the sample code provided by Amazon they do a POST to this address:

```
POST /auth/o2/token HTTP/l.l
```

However I'm not including  `HTTP/l.l` on my `base_url`. I'm not sure if that would play a role in this problem.

**UPDATE #2**

I could generate an access token using the following curl command on my cmd terminal (Windows user) following [this](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuideForVendors.md) example:

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=Atzr|IwE....&client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.d67...&client_secret=317dcd..." https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token
```

The response that I got was:

```
{"access_token":"Atza|IwEB...","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

As Tanaike points out its very likely that Google Apps Script might not be able to request to the endpoint.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, I proposes a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I have added an update if it helps somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- The default content type of `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And, UTF-8 is used.
- I'm not sure whether the special characters are included in the values of `REFRESH_TOKEN`, `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET`. So, how about reflecting the URL encode?

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var base_url = 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token';
var pointParams = "?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + encodeURIComponent(REFRESH_TOKEN) + "&client_id=" + encodeURIComponent(CLIENT_ID) + "&client_secret=" + encodeURIComponent(CLIENT_SECRET);
var query_string = base_url + pointParams;
var options = {
  'method' : 'POST',
  //'muteHttpExceptions': true
};
```

#### Note:

- Please confirm whether your values of `REFRESH_TOKEN`, `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` are the valid values again.
- By the way, your question says `For that we would need the following inputs:grant_type (parameter) refresh_token (input) scope (parameter) client_id (input) client_secret (input)`. But, it seems that your script doesn't include `scope`.

### Added:

From your updated question, when your following curl command works fine,

> `curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=Atzr|IwE....&client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.d67...&client_secret=317dcd..." https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token`

The Google Apps Script is required to be modified. Because your curl command sends the data as the form data. So could you please test the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set the variables and test it.

```
var base_url = 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token';
var options = {
  method: "post",
  payload: {
    grant_type: "refresh_token",
    refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN,
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
  },
  // muteHttpExceptions: true
};
var rawData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(base_url, options).getContentText();
Logger.log(rawData)
```

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, I'll test this out.
About your second note, when the grand_type is equal to "refresh token", the scope parameter is not necessary. I'll edit my question so point out that part of the documentation.

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying and adding information. About the scope, I could understand it. If my proposed modification was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Update: I was able to test this out but I still got the 500 error. The refresh token has some special characters. I also want to mention that I have ommited this part  HTTP/l.l  from the example "POST /auth/o2/token HTTP/l.l" in my solution. I'm not sure if that plays a role

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I checked the official document, I found `Tip: Refresh tokens contain characters that are outside the allowed range for URLs. Therefore, you should URL encode access tokens to prevent errors.`. [Ref](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/retrieve-token-other-platforms-cbl-docs.html#using-refresh-tokens) From this situation, when you use `encodeURIComponent` for only `REFRESH_TOKEN`, what result will you obtain? Unfortunately, I cannot test this. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tanaike. Sadly I encountered the same 500 error. One thing I'm worried about is that I'm not using the right credentials, this API from is pretty new and it has been quite troublesome. However if the credentials were wrong I'm not sure if we would get a 500 error or something different.

Comment: I think the credentials are fine based on an article so I'm wondering if there could be something else to do to the code? I haven't specified the host name, for example.

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying. I think that the request of Google Apps Script is the same with [the request of official document](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/retrieve-token-other-platforms-cbl-docs.html#using-refresh-tokens). About `I haven't specified the host name`, in this case, I think that the host and path are `api.amazon.com` and `/auth/o2/token`, respectively. So in this case, the endpoint is `https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token`.

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo For example, how about testing this request in curl command on your terminal? I'm worry that Google Apps Script might not be able to request to the endpoint. When the same error occurs, how about confirming the method for retrieving the values of `REFRESH_TOKEN` again?

Comment: `In my terminal` means in something like postman?

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo I think that postman can be also used for confirming it.

Comment: it worked! I have updated my question (Update #2) with the curl command used.. however it seems, as you pointed out, that we cannot connect using Google Apps Script?:(

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying and testing it. From your added curl command, when I saw your curl command, I noticed that the data is sent as the form data. In this case, Google Apps Script is required to be modified. So I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If your curl command works fine, the Google Apps Script might work. But if the Google Apps Script occurs the same error, I think that Google Apps Script might not be able to request to the endpoint.

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From the result of your testing, it was found that Google Apps Script can be used for this situation. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

`Content-type` `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is not working. Changed it for `"application/json"` and it works:

```js
function AccessToken() {
  var url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token"
  var params= {
    "method":"POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "client_id":CLIENT_ID,
      "client_secret":CLIENT_SECRET,
      "grant_type":"refresh_token",
      "refresh_token":REFRESH_TOKEN
      //"scope":"appstore::apps:readwrite"
    })
  };
  var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText());
  Logger.log(response)
  return response.access_token
}
```